# US county-level temporal economic data

Tags: data-request, usa, economics

For a research project I'm very interested in economic data such as unemployment rate on a monthly basis for individual counties in the US. Is this available somewhere?

I know that the information I'm requesting is quite detailed. Perhaps someone has made a model that makes reliable predictions on a monthly basis? I'd be very interested in that as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [U.S. Bureau of Labor Statistics](https://www.bls.gov/home.htm) publishes Local Area Unemployment Statistics (LAUS). These provide unemployment rates at various geographic levels: in states, metropolitean areas but also in counties. The summary can be found [here](https://www.bls.gov/lau/lauov.htm).

You might have to apply for the data, though.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Do you know if there's similiar datasets for other economic indicators?

Comment: Maybe. Depends on which economic indicators you are looking for. For the structure of this site, it would be best if you ask another question specifying the economic indicators you are looking for. This way anyone sees the question and we (me or others) can help you there.